# How To show facebook interstitial ads on every screen of android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-javascript-sdk

i want to show interstitial ads on every screen of my app its just showing on home page adding this code i want to open interstitial ads on every screen of my app when someone opens screen ads should show first thankx

Place this code after below line to declare Interstitial Ad

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String TAG = InterstitialAdActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;









then after below line Place Interstitial Ad code

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID");
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad displayed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad dismissed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");
        interstitialAd.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad clicked!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad impression logged!");
    }
});
interstitialAd.loadAd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd interstitial;
Ad adfacebook;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    interstitial = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this,"YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID");

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AbstractAdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            adfacebook = ad;


        }
    });
    interstitial.loadAd();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (adfacebook == interstitial) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: i also have some buttons in the app want to show ads when someone click on button thankx